# Hide native/bot buttons in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

How can I hide the native buttons in Flutter? I'd like to enable them by swiping up but by default I need them hidden.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);`

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This is where you put the code
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);

    // SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.top, SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
    // SystemUiOverlay.top is status bar, SystemUiOverlay.bottom is Navigation bar, if you want to remove both, don't pass anything inside.

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where should I put that?

Comment: it appears hidden but as soon as I touch the screen it pops up and doesn't go away after few seconds. Would be possible to add to it some opacity as well? I saw it in other apps

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemUiOverlay-class.html that's the status bar

Comment: `SystemUiOverlay.top` is status bar, `SystemUiOverlay.bottom` is Navigation bar, if you want to remove both, you need to write `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);`

Comment: You got it. Without anything it goes away after a couple of seconds. Thanks!
PS: edit your question with this last piece

Comment: I found a weird issue: for pages where I don't have a `bottomNavigationBar` it creates an empty space